# validation for gpa in controller laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

how to validation form input for gpa in controller Laravel, with min value 0,00 and max value 4,00.

Now i'm using validate like this

```
'gpa'   =>  'required|max:4|between:0,4|regex:/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\,[0-9]+$/',
```

But if i am input 4,01 or 4,98 validate is true.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is slightly wrong:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*\,[0-9]+$
```

The first part (`[0-9]{1,3}`) captures 1, 2 or 3 digits in the range of 1 to 9. The next part (`(,[0-9]{3})*`) captures zero or more of a comma, followed by 3 more digits. The last part captures a comma and one or more digits.

The next regex should work better:

```
(?:[0-3](,\d{1,2})?)|4,00
```

It captures a digit in the range of 0 to 3, followed by a comma with one or two digits following it (if present), or it captures `4,00`.